# React Native call this.setState inside function

Tags: react-native

I'm using a xml parser `react-native-xml2js` in react native, but this "plugin" uses a specific function for parse the xml, I wasn't found a correct way to use "this" within the function, I've tried using `bind()` in the callback but doesn't work as expected when using bind it fills my variable moments later after executed, so I don't know how to use it, this is my code:

```
  state = { artcicles: null }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://example.com/rss.xml')
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((response) => {
        parseString(response, function (err, result) {
          this.setState({
            articles: JSON.stringify(result.rss.channel[0].item)
          })
          console.log('RAW: '  + result.rss.channel[0].item);
          console.log('THIS: ' + this.state.articles);
        }.bind(this));
      });
  }
```

When calling `this.state.articles` in `render()` at beginning shows `null` but a second later it fills the `articles` variable but at that moment the app shows the error when I'm trying to access to the variable.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can help you observe something. In React, setState is asynchronous, so the code on the following line after setState will be executed immediately after the setState call is placed in the event loop.

Your true issue is that those console.logs are working perfect, you aren't crazy. They are just being executed before setState has completed.

The secret trick here is that setState accepts a second parameter which is a callback that will be executed after the state is updated. You could place all your following logic inside that statement.

Here is a sampler pack:

```
this.setState({ dogs: 350 }, () => { console.log('The state has been updated.') })
```

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.
>
> Cite: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

In yours, it could look like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://example.com/rss.xml')
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((response) => parseString(response, (err, result) =>
            this.setState({
                articles: JSON.stringify(result.rss.channel[0].item),
            }, () => {
                console.log('RAW:', result.rss.channel[0].item)
                console.log('THIS:', this.state.articles)
            }));
        );
}
```

Checkout the modification I did on the console.log. It too can accept multiple parameters.

> A list of JavaScript objects to output. The string representations of each of these objects are appended together in the order listed and output. Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call console.log(), but it is the value of the object at the moment you click it open.
>
> Cite: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

I like that definition additionally because it speaks to the asynchronous nature of live references. One function by itself can be synchronous, but due to the callstack and function queue, you can load up an infinite number of functions into the queue and they will complete in a random order based on how long each one takes to complete because only one passes through the callstack at a time, on the main thread. Of course, it seems random order to us, but it's actually the mathematically exact fastest path through all those functions, assuming they are all deterministic.

Fast forward to the code in your question, setState doesn't care to stop surrounding code from executing unless you explicitly tell it to. That's what the callback is for, if you need to run some bonus code.

While we are talking about `setState`, I should mention also that you can pass a function to it. Imagine that the second parameter callback is your method of looking into the future after setState. The opposite of that is looking into the past, which is where the functional setState comes in handy by giving you closure around the previous unit of time. The previous state also happens to be the current state of whatever you are updating.

Here is a sampler pack for that:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    // hello I like cats.gif
    // we could run some fascinating code here
    // as long as we return an object
    console.log('rad')

    return {
        articles: [ ...prevState.articles, { new: 1, article: true }],
    }
})
```

It gives you a safe window to guarantee state integrity through your update. I showed that example there as spreading an Array into a new Array and appending it with an object to demonstrate similar to a real scenario you might need to refer to the current state as part of your operations.

In a real scenario, you might sharpen that up to this, which capitalizes on implicit return of an Object literal (requires fat arrow syntax):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    articles: [ ...prevState.articles, { new: 1, article: true }],
})
```

Hopefully that helps us see the climate of what is happening. In React, it is important to undergo a formal change management process, so every time you are getting or setting data, you need to be careful who is reading or writing data and from where, like which functions and which part of the program. React's way of taming JavaScript is to try to force data to always flow unidirectionally, immutably, and deterministic.

It makes things easier to `reason about` if everything is flowing one way. That only works if you require immutability and prefer a deterministic system. It means most functions are written declaratively, so they declare what the state looks like at the start of a function, do stuff, then declare what the state is at the end of the function.

React makes you think you are writing mostly pure JavaScript, but really it is managing your state using a first in, first out technique to avoid race conditions when perhaps thousands of components are trying to write to the state at the same time. While the user is in the browser rolling their face across the keyboard triggering all kinds of events, and we must not block the main thread or else suffer poor UX.

A formal change management process means there is probably an official pattern that you should use every time you get or set data. Luckily, the patterns are usually what you would do if you were writing pure JavaScript. Reactive programming and immutability help tame the wild asynchronous concurrency gods.

Sorry, we are digressing a bit, but I had to do it for science.

> TLDR,

it's very important what you are doing before, during, and after `this.setState()`. It's a special function, a class method on the Component Class. I hope I have helped us understand a couple of its secrets today.

You were seeking to perform two operations in one setState call. Normally, you only do one which is to set the state :) Your intended usage is fine. We do nest one additional dimension, but it's fine because you are just performing one more operation. I wouldn't recommend it if you were doing a chain of functions in the callback.

Notice the React documentation that states,

> Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

The reason it says that is `componentDidUpdate()` is listening for state changes, so you can run logic there that is listening for certain conditions and then acting. It saves you from having to care about performing a second operation after setState at the callsite.

Imagine you did **this.state.hasFetchedStuff = true** inside your `componentDidMount()` and then had something like this in `componentDidUpdate()`:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.hasFetchedStuff) {
        this.triggerSomething()
    }
}
```

That can free your componentDidMount from having to care about anything after getting the data, which is perhaps good decoupling and a nice separation of concerns.

I converted this post into a Medium article as well and added much more detail: https://medium.com/@agm1984/reacts-setstate-is-a-special-function-and-it-helps-with-asynchronous-concurrency-669eddbe3dd1

Comment: Thank you for took the time and publish the article, it clear things up not just for this issue, but for other that I faced on my project. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the render() method you can use an [inline If](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator):

```
{this.state.articles && (
  // Display articles
)}
```

When `articles` stops being null the element right after && will appear and while it's null, no errors will be thrown.

Comment: It doesn't work, it seems that it renders the views and after it calls this.setState, it's weird actually.

Comment: You have to use the 'inline if' inside the JSX code that is returned by the render() method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `null` for the initial value you can use an empty array `[]`. That way your `articles` state variable is never in a consistent state. Also, you can avoid having a manual bind in your callback and use arrow functions instead which will keep the current scope. This way you'll have the correct closure to use `this.state`.

```js
parseString(response, (err, result) => {
  this.setState({
    articles: JSON.stringify(result.rss.channel[0].item)
  })
});
```

Comment: I was using articles as an empty array, I changed for test purposes, could you please explain what's a consistent state?... Also I've tried with arrow referencing before but this way doesn't work at all.

Comment: Consistent state for an array means that any point you should be able to call .map on the value. Initializing the value as null is an inconsistent state which .map can’t be called on it

Answer (score 0):

This answer to some tricky

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://example.com/rss.xml')
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((response) => {
        parseString(response, function (err, result) {
          this.setState({
            articles: JSON.stringify(result.rss.channel[0].item)
          })
          console.log('RAW: '  + result.rss.channel[0].item);
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('THIS: ' + this.state.articles);
}, 1000);

        }.bind(this));
      });
  }
```